# Intructions vs cycles per second - what is actually measured in Hertz?

Tags: performance, cpu, performancecounter, cpu-speed

So I am going through some tutorials, and it seems they keep using "instructions" and "cycles" interchangeably, so now I am confused what is actually measured in Hertz (on the most **basic** level, without going into what the modern processors can do in parallel etc, trying to learn the basics here).

Say, the program is as follows: load two numbers, add them, store result.
So there will be 4 cycles:

1. load number A [fetch-decode-execute]
2. load number B [fetch-decode-execute]
3. add A and B [fetch-decode-execute]
4. store result [fetch-decode-execute]

**What is a *cycle* here, and what is an *instruction*?**

There are **4 cycles**, or **12 instructions**, correct?

Say, it takes CPU **1 sec** to run this program.
What will be the CPU clock speed? **12 instructions/1 sec** or **4 cycles/1 sec**?

- If the former one, then is the clock speed of the CPU **12 Hertz**?
- If the latter one, then is the clock speed of the CPU **4 Hertz**?

Comment: You have written a program that contains 4 instructions.  It sounds like you are assuming each instruction takes 3 clock cycles to run (though it is unlikely to be so simple on any advanced processor).  So if it runs in 1 second, the clock speed is 12 cycles per second, aka 12 Hz.

Comment: If you could quote a particular passage from one of the tutorials that's confusing you, someone might be able to help explain it more clearly.

Comment: @NateEldredge so is "fetch" one _cycle_ or one _instruction_? I thought a "cycle" was referring to the "fetch-decode-execute".

Comment: this video, she mentions both "cycle" and "instruction" but I am confused which one refers to what https://youtu.be/FZGugFqdr60?list=PL8dPuuaLjXtNlUrzyH5r6jN9ulIgZBpdo&t=510 "The speed at which a CPU can carry out each step of "fetch-decode-execute" CYCLE is measured in Hertz"

Comment: I see.  The word "cycle" is generic, just referring to any instance of a repetitive process.  Depending on context, it could refer to a *clock* cycle (one clock tick) or a sequence of events that takes several clock ticks (e.g. a *fetch-decode-execute* cycle).  It's more commonly used to mean "clock cycle" but that doesn't mean other usages are wrong if they are clarified.

Comment: The *instructions* in your example are what you have numbered 1,2,3,4, e.g. "load number A".  Each corresponds to a single line of assembly code, or a particular sequence of bytes of machine code, that have a particular effect on the state of the machine as seen by the programmer (e.g. contents of registers and memory).   "Fetch, decode and execute" are sometimes called **stages** of the instruction's execution, but they are not themselves instructions as they can't happen in isolation.

Comment: You might find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_cycle to be helpful.

Comment: If a fetch-decode-execute cycle is one cycle, then why the clock speed is not 4Hz but 12 Hz?

Comment: A fetch-decode-execute cycle is one **instruction cycle**, but three **clock cycles**.  The clock speed measures the number of **clock cycles** per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From helpful comments by @Nate Eldredge:

"A fetch-decode-execute cycle is one **instruction** cycle, but three **clock** cycles.

The clock speed measures the number of clock cycles per second."

Thus, if the program is executed within 1 second, and it takes 12 clock cycles, the clock speed of that particular CPU is **12** Hz.